# Search within my answers/questions/favorites

Tags: discussion, support, search, bookmarks

Sometimes I want to search within my answers/questions for various reasons:

1. After finding new things and I want to update my answer.
2. When faced with a problem to which I already got an answer here.

But unfortunately, if you have lots of answers/questions, it is hard, almost impossible, to find the answer/question you are looking for.

I have been thinking that it would be great to have that feature to facilitate navigation in old posts.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Try this on Meta Stack Overflow:

```
user:1503155 is:question  
user:1503155 is:answer  
in:saves
```

Also works:

```
user:me is:question  
user:me is:answer
```

More info on:

[A new search engine for Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160100/a-new-search-engine-for-stack-exchange)

In October 2022, the ["bookmark" functionality was turned into "saves" functionality](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382019), changing the search syntax as well.

**Edit** - in response to OP's comment.

One can easily access the "Advanced Search Tips", beside the question search box. See screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: Why they did not implement drop down select box for search?!

Comment: @sємsєм, I don't know, but I guess it is easier this way, where one can set the parameters for some types of searches (e.g. score:x).