# How can I search for related posts based on a search string that matches in my favorites tab?

Tags: discussion, bookmarks

I have a habit of adding the questions which I found useful to my favorites. Currently I have **4,541** questions.

I'm wondering how I can search for **related posts** based on a search string that matches a word or a pair of words or multiple words in a sentence.

For example, if I want to search for posts which contain a words like *strong parameters*, *nested attributes* then how can I pick the posts which contain those strings?

The sorting feature in favorites doesn't help in my case. I had looked in to several posts on Meta SO, but I couldn't find any of those useful to me. The closest one I found is [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258415/search-within-my-answers-questions-favorites) post. But how can I use that technique in my case?

Can anyone please shed light on this? I'm very grateful for any helpful suggestions.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're looking for besides searching within your favorites, which is explained in the linked post and the advanced search help.

Comment: @Mat Apologies.But i'm having a hard time finding that **Advance Search link**.Where can i find it?

Comment: There's a picture in the post you link to.

Comment: @Mat Thanks! finally figured it out how to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well at first I'm a bit confused in using the technique in the link which i attached.Now figured it out.I'm posting as answer so it may be helpful to someone.

**Step 1**

```
infavorites:2346461 OR infavorites:mine
```

It gave me the list of all my favorites.Here `2346461` is **user id**

**Step 2**

Now i entered the relevant words as search input

```
"nested attributes" "strong parameters"
```

Yes.now it gives the **list of my favorites which contains those words**.