# How to search in favorite post using keywords?

Tags: bug, search, bookmarks

So, I have some hundreds favorite posts and I want to search between them some that contains "git" + "branch" words.

I could find the post passing one by one but I was wondering if we have that functionality already or not.

Following this [post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260011/how-can-i-search-for-related-posts-based-on-a-search-string-that-matches-in-my-f) it seems that something is wrong when I use `infavorites:git infavorites:branch` because I don't have that amount of posts inside my favorites.

[image]

So is it possible to perform this kind of search only inside my favorites?

Comment: `infavorites:me "git branch"` should do it

Comment: It’s `infavorites:mine`, not `infavorites:me`.

Comment: As far as I can tell, you can use `mine` and `me` interchangeably anywhere in search.

Comment: Yes Both worked for me.