# Search for all my posts across sites

Tags: discussion, search, stack-exchange

How can I search all my posts across different Stack Exchange sites?

E.g. I have posted in Stack Overflow and [Emacs.SE](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/14843/lucky1928) community, but when I search in Stack Overflow, I can not see posts in Emacs.

I have to switch to the Emacs site to search it. It's really inconvenient.

My question is **not** a duplicate of [Search within my answers/questions/favorites](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258415/search-within-my-answers-questions-favorites) as that only explains how to search within a single site whereas I'm looking for a way to search for my question across two or more sites I participate/have an account on.

Comment: @KevinB here Emacs is [a site in SE network](https://emacs.stackexchange.com), I think

Comment: You can [look through your network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/2160535/lucky1928) to see your top posts, but you cannot search both places at once for just your posts. The search used by stackexchange.com can't filter by user, so it can't be used for this either.

Comment: That is not a dupe, it's not about *across sites*

Comment: You can use the query mentioned [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/297358/295232) (but it's in Spanish).