# Are there usage statistics for favourites?

Tags: discussion, statistics, bookmarks

I have >700 questions favourited, from the almost seven years I've been on Stack Overflow.

I don't know if I've ever browsed or [searched](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258415/search-within-my-answers-questions-favorites) my favourites list.

Are there any usage statistics about:

- What percentage of users click the favourite star, and how frequently.
- What percentage of users who do favourite questions - later revist those questions via the favourites list.
- How often are people searching using the `isfavourite:..` search term.

Comment: The first bullet can be answered with some SEDE magic. Here is one to start with : https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/898516

Comment: I like using favourites so that I can tell when I end up finding a question using Google that previously helped me solve an issue

Comment: I track changes in favourites to ensure that the changes (edits, new answers) are OK.  That is, I mark questions that I care about as favourites, and endeavour to ensure they aren't damaged.

Comment: I'd love to know how many people favorite their *own* question, especially if they favorite it "very soon" after asking it. Then I want to know why they think that's useful...

Comment: 25K favorites here, which is why I asked: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/286057/6309

Comment: @SeinopSys You might want to consider using upvotes for that :-)

Comment: @Bergi I upvote as well, but I also upvote other content, not just stuff that helped me out, so having that star there in addition is a clear indicator that this is a known good path, so to speak.

Comment: I've seen several high-rep users talk about favouriting questions as a way of checking up on problematic questions in the short-term. Also some mention marking those questions which they plan to come back to later once they have more time. Personally I seem to favourite totally random questions then forget all about them (at least that's how it seems looking at them now!). Favourites seem to fit a variety of use cases, not just the "this is really useful for reference" use-case you seem to have in mind.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Running from [rene's query](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374138/are-there-usage-statistics-for-favourites?cb=1#comment630620_374138), here's some data I compiled for the first bullet point:

[861,768](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/899131/1117915/number-of-users-that-have-favorited-something) user accounts have at least one favorited post. That's 9% of the [9,384,287](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/899132/1117917/total-users-on-the-site) current accounts.

Looking at the [breakdown by frequency](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/899134/1117919/frequency-of-favorite-votes), most people have under 1,000 favorites, with a majority of those under 10.

[image]

Remember, both axes are log scale.

Breaking this down [by reputation](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/899457/1118325/avg-favorite-vote-count-by-rep), we see that there is a narrow band for people with less than 1k rep. Over 1k rep, the number of favorites varies greatly.

[image]

Comment: I am the bottom-right one, and the top-right one (because of https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/286057/6309), with 25K favorites.