# Can I search for questions that I previously "thanked"? And is my "thank" therefore public?

Tags: support, reactions

When I click [the currently-being-tested thank-you button](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/06/17/saying-thanks-testing-a-new-reactions-feature/), who can see that I am the one who said "thank you"?

Similarly, can the thank-you button be used for bookmarking pages so that I can revisit them? (This is what eventually happened to the star feature.)

Bookmarks have the advantage over up-votes that they are searchable. E.g., [here are my meta bookmarks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/272229/josiah-yoder?tab=bookmarks), and [here I am searching for Keras among questions that I have favorited](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=infavorites%3A1048186+keras&mixed=1). (Upvotes are (sadly) not searchable. This is to protect the privacy of upvotes, but a user cannot search for a question they have previously upvoted.)

I can see a new user desiring to return to their previously-thanked questions so they can convert them to upvotes once they have enough reputation to vote, and I can see seasoned users desiring to find a question that they liked so much the decided to both up-vote and "thank" the author, but didn't bother saving it in favorites.

But I have no idea about the social implications of "thanks" being public...

Thanks to [Andre Silva](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258417/1048186) for showing me how to search within my favorites.

Comment: [Your upvotes are actually searchable](/users/current?tab=votes)

Comment: @pppery Wow! Useful to know. And now public, too.  It didn't used to be like that did it?

Comment: It's not public, it's visible only to you.

Comment: @ppery Through the link you pasted, they are viewable, but not searchable.

Comment: I don't see what distinguishes the bookmarks link that you call "searchable" from the upvotes link I posted, which you say isn't.

Comment: @pppery [Searching for Keras within my favorites](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=infavorites%3A1048186+keras&mixed=1)

Comment: Your _Thanks_ are public though, visible in post timelines of questions you thanked. One of the many issues of the thank you system is that this fact is not obvious at all. If they're also searcheable for others is unclear to me.

Comment: It's nice that when I "thank" and quickly "unthank" that my thanks are not visible in the history as noise.  And I agree -- this is not obvious to the users most likely to care -- new users who can't upvote yet.

Comment: Oh good heavens. A thank you button, you say? (－‸ლ)

Comment: @ruffin Look at the latest blog post

Answer (score 3):

> Similarly, can the thank-you button be used for bookmarking pages so that I can revisit them? (This is what eventually happened to the star feature.)

There is a tab in your profile for *reaction* which can be accessed by the following link:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/users/ID?tab=votes&sort=reaction
```

Here you can view every post you reacted on. This will be useful for a <15 rep user because they can upvote the posts they have reacted on.

> I can see a new user desiring to return to their previously-thanked questions so they can convert them to upvotes once they have enough reputation to vote, and I can see seasoned users desiring to find a question that they liked so much the decided to both up-vote and "thank" the author, but didn't bother saving it in favorites.

As this feature is currently in a “testing phase”, I don’t think a searchable feature will be added to this yet.

If it gets rolled out, it would be nice to be able to search `thanked:1` or `reacted:1` which will show every post you have reacted on with *thanks*.