# Organizing Bookmarks

Tags: discussion, bookmarks

I have over 100 bookmarks on Stack Overflow and I was trying to purge some that I didn't think were as essential, but I find that I don't want to lose them. Is there any way to organize them or search through them? It would be nice if there was an easy way to find all the bookmarks I have on a particular technology.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Search within my answers/questions/favorites](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258415/search-within-my-answers-questions-favorites) (`infavorites` is now `inbookmarks`) ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=inbookmarks%3Amine+%5Bjavascript%5D))

Comment: Can you just move them to an external list and organise them there?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Can you export bookmarks from stackoverflow to a file?