# Allow users to create custom categories into which to sort bookmarks

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, bookmarks

I noticed that in the bookmarks section of Stack Overflow, all the bookmarks are presented together, so one has to look or go through the complete list of bookmarks to find a particular one.

My suggestion/feature request is that we (each user) should be able to create separate categories of bookmarks where we can put the bookmarks according to a category. For example, let us say I created 3 separate bookmark folders/sections named **C++, Python, and Perl**. Now whenever I want to bookmark a specific post (let us say C++ specific), then I should be able to put that post in the C++ bookmark folder. Similarly for others as well.

By the way, this feature is available on many different sites. So I would like to see it here as well as it will definitely increase our productivity level (even if by a little) and also the bookmarks section will look aesthetically pleasing as well. So basically when a user clicks on the bookmark option on a particular post then they should be presented with a dialog box to select/create a particular bookmark folder to put the post in.

**Summary:**

I want to create arbitrary named categories and put the questions that I want in those. For example, I may create a category named "Sports" and put some posts there similarly I may create a bookmark folder/category called "animations" and put some posts there. The same feature is also present in Instagram.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Organizing Bookmarks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402054/organizing-bookmarks)

Comment: No that does not answer my question @Yatin. I think that this should be simple feature that should be available on Stack Overflow. That question is certainly the same as this but it had no concrete answers. This(mine) question can only be answered correctly if i get a certain reply from the working member of the stack overflow team of whether or not they want to implement this feature or not. Otherwise many different people can answer for or against this feature but that still wont answer my question.

Comment: @Yatin The linked post is a discussion, that links to another discussion. None of those are feature-requests. The last one gives a workaround. Also the workaround does not f.ex. allow for a "known canonical"-folder, nor a "My favorite newbies"-folder :)

Comment: Related, but not a duplicate: [Search within my answers/questions/favorites](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258415/search-within-my-answers-questions-favorites). That question has an answer which explains searching within your bookmarks. However, it's not a feature request asking for categories within your bookmarks (and presumably that you can select from you bookmark page).

Comment: Seems similar to [this MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100736/categorize-stack-overflow-favorite-questions) feature request.

Answer (score 8):

I've created a userscript (available on Stack Apps) called ["StackMarks™"](https://stackapps.com/questions/8955/stackmarks-better-bookmarks-for-a-better-experience) which enables you to categorize your bookmarks.

It has a dashboard where you can view the current bookmarks and create new categories. Instructions for use are in the link above, but here's a general overview.

#### Dashboard

Creating new categories by clicking the 'New Category' button:

[image: StackMarks™ - Demo 1 - Dashboard]

#### Adding bookmark to category

Once installed, a '+SM' button will appear below the standard bookmarks icon. Once clicked, this will prompt you a dialog, from which you can choose the category:

[image: StackMarks™ - Demo 2 - Add Category Dialog]

#### Result:

[image: StackMarks™ - Demo 3 - Result]

It also packs some extra features, like searching. note taking etc,.

If you have accumulated a lot of bookmarks, StackMarks provides the ability to "import" these bookmarks over.

Answer (score 4):

This can also be achieved by filtering, for example using `inbookmarks:mine [tag:language]` in the [search functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching).

Comment: No i do not want to search the bookmarks by a tag at all. I want to create arbitrary named categories and put the questions that i want in those. For example, i may create a category named "Sports" and put some posts there similarly i may create a bookmark folder/category called "animations" and put some posts there. The same feature is also present in instagram.

Comment: @JasonLiam how about you use your browsers bookmarks then?

Comment: @JasonLiam as Braiam said, just create a bookmark folder for each section. On Stack Overflow, tags are the categories we sort questions by.

Comment: @Braiam and 10Rep the question is about how can i do it in Stack Overflow and not through my browser. Since Stack Overflow is a very popular code related site with many users, i think it should have this feature and there should not be any difficulty in implementing this. That is  i am talking about Stack overflow's functionality and not my browser's functionality. This feature is a must(IMO) for a site like Stack Overflow.

Comment: "and there should not be any difficulty in implementing this" says the guy who hasn't implemented the feature... Sorry, but whenever anyone says "it should be easy" I can't stay quiet. You have no idea what kind of pressures or constraints Stack Overflow's developers are coding under.

Comment: Have they still got that giant "S" hanging over the entryway, @HereticMonkey?

Comment: @CodyGray I think it's got a line going through the middle now... ;)

Comment: @JasonLiam why should Stack Overflow have this feature? I don't think it should, and honestly, I don't find it necessary, and I find it a waste of tim.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I did not say/mean that the devs have to implement this right now or in a week. They can decide for themselves on the basis of 1) the usability(or frequency, which means how often the user will use this feature) , 2) Will this save time for the user of this feature 3) how much resource(in terms of time) will it take to implement this. Also i still stand by the statement that "there should not be any difficulty in implementing this". You can look at Spectric's answer/userscript for reference. If you think implementing this hard in any way, you must really not know programming.

Answer (score 2):

Finally this has been implemented and "Bookmarks" has been [renamed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382019/bookmarks-have-evolved-into-saves?cb=1) to "Saves".

Now it is possible to categorize your bookmarks into lists.

[image]

After clicking on this highlighted icon you'll get:

[image]

And if you click on the dropdown button shown above you'll have the option of creating a new list and saving the post in that list.