# Additional Features for Bookmarks

Tags: feature-request, bookmarks

Bookmarks would be highly valuable, especially older ones, if:

1. One could add custom notes. It would prevent from reading through all answers of older bookmarks just to find out what is a 1-liner in a custom note like "answer from userXYZ most relevant but he got abc wrong".
2. Bookmarks could be grouped by custom topics (not mandatory). Probably duplicate of [Allow users to create custom categories into which to sort bookmarks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/407509/allow-users-to-create-custom-categories-into-which-to-sort-bookmarks)
3. Bookmarks would show relevant changes since one added/last visited the bookmark, such as "5 new answers", "significant downvotes", or "might be old solution (indicated by newer related questions)"
4. I could imagine that bookmarks would turn into a starting point for some users who always return to a bookmark group with a topic of permanent interest (custom for each user, see 2) like "browser updates" or "JS frameworks" if additionally new related questions (to the custom topic) are shown. This is a more customizable solution than subscribing to tags.

Comment: This is a recurring feature request that never seems to get much traction but sure would be nice to have. There have been several similar requests just in the last month or so. An *in page* filter would be another feature to add to this list. Full page reloads to find something is pretty old school in the age of single page interactive apps

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/407509/allow-users-to-create-custom-categories-into-which-to-sort-bookmarks

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; a lengthy back-and-forth conversation involving multiple users has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233477/discussion-on-question-by-chriscross-additional-features-for-bookmarks).

Comment: Made a [userscript](https://stackapps.com/questions/8955/stackmarks-better-bookmarks-for-a-better-experience) for this question which covers point 1, 2 and 3.