# Allow exporting and importing Saves links/data

Tags: feature-request, saves, export

Now that Bookmarks has been renamed to Saves and we have the option to create lists within Saves, I think that users should be able to **export** and possibly **import** Saves data.

For example, suppose I currently have 3 lists in my Saves, so I want to be able to export that data (the 3 lists). Similarly, I want to have an option to import the previously exported Saves data.

One use of this is that this can help increase collaboration between people. Like those who are working in teams etc. People in a team can just export the Saves data at the end of the week (or month etc.) so that each person in the team will be able to see all the important links saved by all the members of the team within SE's network itself.

Note that I know that this is also possible using browser's bookmark feature, but I want this to be possible within Stack Overflow because the nice organized view and categorical and visual presentation of SO's Saves is way better than that of a browser's bookmarks tab.

Answer (score 4):

I support this feature. I think that if it is added, there should be two buttons next to *"Edit list"*, like this:

[image]

<sup>(Please forgive the bad editing)</sup>

When you click *"Import data"*, it should let you paste in a list of question links, and when you click *"Export data"*, it should show you a list of question links which you can copy. I don't think this will be too difficult to implement.

Comment: Preferably in a standard format like [tag:csv]

Comment: @TheMaster yes, I agree. I just forgot to mention that in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

My userscript, [SavedPostsHelper](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/SavedPostsHelper.user.js), allows you to export/import your saves from/to **the current list**.

**Buttons:**

[image]

**Export:**

[image]

**Import:**

[image]

SavedPostsHelper also adds other features like bulk moving checkboxes between lists, quick-move dropdown after a post is saved, and more.

Answer (score -1):

On its face I disagree with this request because the use case seems contrived.  Working in a large group, I find it far more expedient to just send the link of what I'm looking at to someone as opposed to them needing to have gone through the process of signing up for an account and then needing to import my bookmarks.  We can't just assume that everyone on a team (not Stack Overflow for Teams, mind) has a Stack Overflow account, since one has never had a hard requirement for one up until now.

Comment: No, sending a link is very inefficient. The way the posts are displayed in Saves is very elegant and efficient.

Comment: @JasonLiam:  If I send someone a link in Teams or Slack, I lose literally *no* efficiency.  Again, there is a hard requirement that someone has to have a Stack Overflow account to make use of this feature.  Links are very accessible for a very large demographic.  Saves are exclusive to Stack Overflow and are very much a walled garden.

Comment: I agree that there is no(and there should be no) requirement to use SO. I am not saying that everyone "must" use SO. I am saying that whoever uses it already. And this feature is for those who uses SO.

Comment: @JasonLiam: "Using" SO is not the same as "being registered on SO".  Links let you use SO.  Saves require you to be registered on SO.  **These are not the same thing.**

Comment: Ofcourse Saves requires us to be registered on SO. Also only SO posts can be saved. But that is the point. I am only taking about SO/SE posts and for users who are part of the SO/SE community.

Comment: @JasonLiam:  This is why I disagree with it.  It's not widely useful.  It's useful only for those SO/SE users who are in the ecosystem.  But if you're not, then it's no more beneficial for you than using links.

Comment: In what universe that you live is "sending a link very inefficient"? I really cannot understand this claim. And why would you be so frequently sharing *an entire list* of Stack Overflow Q&A with *an entire team* of colleagues? This makes no sense as a workflow.

Comment: @CodyGray Sharing links is inefficient and inelegant because apart from the link we can't see anything(like content inside) from the link. But in SO's Saves list when we click on any of the list, then we get a nice organized view with clear titles of the post and a peek at the content of the posts. This makes is much better than just sharing a bunch of links.

Comment: @JasonLiam:  Where I work, if I'm having a conversation with a developer about some resource on Stack Overflow, there is implied and express context into what I'm talking about with them.  Sharing the link doesn't do anything to harm that context.  Sure, it means that someone who stumbles across our chat conversation weeks later may not know what we're talking about, but *the link wasn't for them to begin with*.  Also too, Teams, Discord and Slack *do* expand the link a little bit so that you get some additional info about the link, too.

Comment: @JasonLiam:  I can at least see your use case if I squint hard enough, but your justifications for it are flatly false.  I am, from experience of having done this for over ten years, stating that there isn't an efficiency hit when I share a link from Stack Overflow.  It might be inelegant, but what you find elegant may not be what I find elegant.  You'll want to do something to sell this idea to me.  We've managed for decades without this feature and being able to share a bunch of links to something; why does it all of a sudden make sense to have it now?  That's the question I need answered.

Comment: @Makoto Because now that [this feature request has been completed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/407509/allow-users-to-create-custom-categories-into-which-to-sort-bookmarks) and renamed to `Saves`. Before this, there was no way to have bookmarks categorically on SO. Now that we have it, that's why the question is asked at this time. My point is that there is nothing wrong with make a feature even better. And IMO adding the import/export option will make the Saves feature better.

Comment: @JasonLiam:  I'm quite skeptical if Saves are going to be useful beyond the sentiment of a few people keeping tabs on a few answers or power users/moderators keeping tabs on a giant voting ring or fraud.  But your argument has *shifted* from "sharing information more efficiently" to "because we can now group things we should be able to share them".  This is why I'm skeptical.  If I get 20 links out of context to something, I'm not going to follow any of them.  If I get one link in context, I'll follow it.  If I don't have an SO account, I'm not going to be able to follow *any* of those links.

Comment: @JasonLiam:  And *that* is the key counterpoint here.  **There are a LOT of people who do not have a Stack Overflow account, and yet use Stack Overflow every day.** Creating a feature which boxes out the lion's share of user attention on the site does not sound like a good use of dev resources.  The usefulness piece I've already beaten to death at this point.

Comment: @Makoto Just because there are a lot of people who do not have a SO account and yet use SO everyday doesn't mean that SO should stop adding features to their site. This feature-request will be very useful to users like me who uses Saves very frequently and have 100s of items saved in many lists. That is why i made the [original feature request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/407509/allow-users-to-create-custom-categories-into-which-to-sort-bookmarks) so that users who frequently use SO bookmarks can save bookmarks categorically.